# How to join two table with JSON data id with another table column id

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `preference` JOIN contact_preference ON preference.id IN  (JSON_EXTRACT(contact_preference.preference_ids,'$')) WHERE contact_preference.contact = 'blahblah.com'
```

O/p

```
  ["Y2NuYW"]
["X8AHZg", "yhTq0w"]
```

Need

```
"X8AHZg", "yhTq0w"
```

so, i can search this in IN paramters

Comment: Ideally if you can normalize also your example data does not seam to be valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL version 5.7, you can try this solution:

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2e56762e9fa70a3c85ce9f6c4c054da0)

```
-- Your Data
CREATE TABLE jsontable AS 
SELECT '["X8AHZg", "yhTq0w"]' AS json FROM dual;


-- Solution Starts Here
CREATE TABLE main_table (
     value VARCHAR(1000)
);

-- 1. create procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1()
BEGIN
SET @index := 0;
SELECT @jsonlength := MAX(JSON_LENGTH(json)) FROM jsontable;

REPEAT
   INSERT INTO main_table (value)
   SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json,CONCAT("$[",@index,"]")) FROM jsontable;
   SET @index = @index + 1;
UNTIL @index = @jsonlength 
END REPEAT;
END;

-- 2. call procedure
CALL proc1;

-- 3. query result
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(value, '"', '') AS value
FROM main_table
```

In short, You can replace your query from this

```
JSON_EXTRACT(contact_preference.preference_ids,'$')
```

to this query after running the procedure

```
SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(value, '"', '') AS value
FROM main_table
```